# Google analytics for android for internal promotion clicks

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to implement internal promotions impression clicks for android. I have successfully implemented the internal promotions impressions. But the clicks for the internal promotion are not reflected on Google Analytics dashboard.

Here is my code for tracking impression clicks

```
 public static void trackImpressionClick(Context context, ArrayList<String> promotionClickStrings){
    Promotion promotion = new Promotion()
            .setId(promotionClickStrings.get(0))
            .setName(promotionClickStrings.get(1))
            .setCreative(promotionClickStrings.get(2))
            .setPosition(promotionClickStrings.get(3));
    ProductAction promoClickAction = new ProductAction(Promotion.ACTION_CLICK);
    HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .addPromotion(promotion)
            .setProductAction(promoClickAction)
            .setCategory("Internal Promotions")
            .setAction("click")
            .setLabel(promotionClickStrings.get(1))
            .setValue(0);

    Tracker promotion_click_tracker = ((BaseApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getTracker(
            BaseApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    promotion_click_tracker.send(builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-promos

it is given wrong as we have to setPromotionAction in Event Buider instead of setProductAction, which did the trick for me.

```
public static void trackImpressionClick(Context context, ArrayList<String> promotionClickStrings) {
    Log.d("NewSearchActivity", promotionClickStrings.get(0));
    Promotion promotion = new Promotion()
            .setId(promotionClickStrings.get(0))
            .setName(promotionClickStrings.get(1))
            .setCreative(promotionClickStrings.get(2))
            .setPosition(promotionClickStrings.get(3));
    ProductAction promoClickAction = new ProductAction(Promotion.ACTION_CLICK);
    HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .addPromotion(promotion)
            .setPromotionAction(Promotion.ACTION_CLICK)
            .setCategory("Internal Promotions")
            .setAction("click")
            .setLabel(promotionClickStrings.get(1));

    Tracker promotion_click_tracker = ((BaseApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getTracker(
            BaseApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    promotion_click_tracker.send(builder.build());
}
```